# How do I get url of uploaded file

Tags: java, apache, ftp

I'm using `apache.commons` library for uploading file to a ftp server. It uploads file successful, but then I want to have a link to that file, that anyone can download it. How do I get the `URL` of uploaded file ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great features of an FTP server is the ability to use direct FTP links. With a direct link, you can use links to files and directories in emails and on your websites. Think of this: instead of sending a big attachment in an email, send a link to the file instead.

The format is really simple:

`ftp:// username [colon] password [at] server.exavault.com [slash] folder-or-filename`

For example: `ftp://links:pass@test.exavault.com/transfer.pdf`

source : http://www.exavault.com/docs/help/faq/transferring/direct-links